# How to programmatically determine if a anchor tag will execute Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xss, csrf

I am enabling users to send messages to each other which contain hyperlinks. However, this also makes it so users can easily perform CSRF and XSS attacks on each other by embedding javascript inside an anchor tag. I want to disallow a message from sending if it contains an anchor tag that will execute JavaScript. How can I programmatically determine if an anchor tag will not execute any JavaScript?

Comment: can you pass around markdown instead of HTML, like SO does? there are tools, but i don't trust them because there's so many ways to code HTML tags in manners that, at a glance, don't look like they would be links or any other tag. see the xss cheatsheet for examples.

Comment: Unfortunately we do not use markdown

Comment: yes, but can you? markdown is plain text, and most engines will hyperlink legit URLs automatically, without fear of the unknown. you just mark up the message text before you display it. easy, safe. you don't have to use it specifically, it won't screw up most plain text messages. if not markdown itself, you still need a structured way to send link URLs aside from HTML snips over the wire.

Comment: Turns out the spec changed and the messages no longer will allow hyperlinks. Thanks anyways!